# Dynamic ui with rows and columns

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to build an ui with a dynamic grid. At least I think a grid is the way to go.
The controls of each cell should be the same, f.e. a `TextBox`.

Each row can have a different number of cells and I thought about using the `ColumnSpan` property to make the ui look like

```
First row, 2 cells
Second row, 3 cells
Third row, 1 cell
```

Each cell should be part of an f.e. `ObservableCollection<MyCellClass>` and should have properties like `Row`, `Column`, `Columnspan`, `Text`.

I know how to build a dynamic grid but I don't know how to set the content of the cells via a template and how to databind the textbox.

Maybe my approach isn't the best and you got some other idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a Grid as the [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) of an ItemsControl, and bind the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property to your ObservableCollection.

Assuming that your cell class looks like this:

```
public class Cell
{
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public int ColumnSpan { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int RowSpan { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

the XAML may be written like shown below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding ColumnSpan}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="{Binding RowSpan}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The following piece of code would initialize two cells of the ItemsControl:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var cells = new ObservableCollection<Cell>();
    cells.Add(new Cell { Column = 0, Row = 0, ColumnSpan = 1, RowSpan = 1, Text = "Cell 1" });
    cells.Add(new Cell { Column = 2, Row = 2, ColumnSpan = 2, RowSpan = 1, Text = "Cell 2" });
    DataContext = cells;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using something like this?

```
public class ItemVm 
{
    // here you can put your desired properties, 
    // although you won't need something like ColumnsSpan etc.
}
```

As underlying structure (viewmodel) for your grid you could use the following property:

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ItemVm>> Rows { get; } // just an illustration
```

Now you only need a `ListView` (or something similar), whose `ItemTemplate` is again a `ListView` (or something similar). The `ItemTemplate` of the inner `ListView` will be the visual representation of `ItemVm`.

Please note, that I'm describing an approach according to the MVVM pattern. So you will need a base class for the viewmodels. But you can find plenty of frameworks on the WWW.