# C# WPF Selecting items in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

To be clear I'm talking about Grid - not GridView or DataGrid or anything like that.
All I found online was about GridView and such.

I want to be able to select items with a mouse click or drag from a Grid.
What I have is a table filled with text implemented through a Grid. I want to be able to select "cells" in the Grid.

The reason I don't use DataGrid is because I couldn't find a way to set a cell's span.

Thank you,
Dolev.

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible because a grid is only a container to arange other 'items'.

Comment: Do you know of any other way to create a table with span-able cells (other than with a Grid)?

Comment: Maybe if you be more specific. I don't know exactly what you want to do. Do you want to show the text in columns and rows or only in columns or rows. Maybe a ListView/ListBox with a Wrappanel?

Comment: I want to be able to show text in columns and rows, Where some of the rows/columns are spanned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used Selector.IsSelected attached property.
[Selector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I modified the MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove event to record a rectangle created when dragging the mouse while the left button is held. Then I checked which cells are within that rectangle.
As a double check to see that the cell is really selected I used Selector.SetIsSelected and Selector.GetIsSelected.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same approach some month ago: [Dynamic ui with rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582247/dynamic-ui-with-rows-and-columns)
Maybe this will help you.